# FTP session code is not working in while/for loop. How to resolve?

Tags: shell, loops, unix, ftp

I have a requirement like this, Read the content of a file X present on server A and connect to server B and get the contents of file X.

My code is

```
set -x
idFile="/tserver/Ravi/logs/FilesToBeCopied.txt"
while read line
do
echo $line
ftp -in hrserver << ! > FtpLog.log
user ravi welcome1
cd /hrserver/kumar/Images
lcd /tserver/Ravi/logs/FTPFiles/
get $line
quit
done < $idFile
```

The error I got is:

```
./myScript.sh
+ idFile=/tserver/Ravi/logs/FilesToBeCopied.txt
./myScript.sh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Tried using for loop also:

```
for line in `cat /tserver/Ravi/logs/FilesToBeCopied.txt`;do
echo $line
echo "$line $FileStorageLocation"
ftp -in hrserver << ! > FtpLog.log
user ravi welcome1
cd /hrserver/kumar/Images
lcd /tserver/Ravi/logs/FTPFiles/
get $line
quit
done
```

I got the same error, ***pointing to the last line of the file and showing syntax error.***

when I tried to run the same script by commenting the while/for loops, the script ran successfully and the ftp was done (here I hard-coded line value). As my requirement is to read each line from the file and perform ftp, I opted for looping.

I am not familiar with shell scripting. My question is, is it possible to incorporate FTP command in a loop? if so, can you help me identify where my code is going wrong and resolve it? if not, can you provide a solution to my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Here-document` is missing it's closing sentinel. (Or you have had a problem with copy paste in your posting).

Try

```
idFile="/tserver/Ravi/logs/FilesToBeCopied.txt"
while read line
do
echo $line
ftp -in hrserver << ! > FtpLog.log
    user ravi welcome1
    cd /hrserver/kumar/Images
    lcd /tserver/Ravi/logs/FTPFiles/
    get $line
    quit
!
done < $idFile
```

Which is why I prefer using a larger token. `EOF` (End Of File) is a common one.

Also recall that `here-docs` allow for indenting of the token inside your shell script if you quote the token, or prefix it with the `-` char, i.e.

```
ftp -in hrserver <<-EOF > ftpLog.log
     .....
<tab>EOF
```

OR

```
<tab><tab>ftp -in hrserver <<'EOF' > ftpLog.log
<tab><tab>   ....
<tab><tab>EOF
```

Or many other combinations as needs be. Get a simple indented Here-doc working first, and then play around for the indenting style you really need.

NOTE: No spaces in front of closing EOF, but spaces inside the here document are left in place, allowing for a small range of formatting.

IHTH